# Should persistent objects validate data upon set?

Tags: language-agnostic, orm, oop, persistence

If one has a object which can persist itself across executions (whether to a DB using ORM, using something like Python's `shelve` module, etc), should validation of that object's attributes be placed within the class representing it, or outside?

Or, rather; should the persistent object be **dumb** and expect whatever is setting it's values to be benevolent, or should it be **smart** and validate the data being assigned to it?

I'm not talking about type validation or user input validation, but rather things that affect the persistent object such as links/references to other objects exist, ensuring numbers are unsigned, that dates aren't out of scope, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My policy is that, for a global code to be robust, each object A should check as much as possible, as early as possible. But the "as much as possible" needs explanation:

- The **internal coherence of each field** B in A (type, range in type etc) should be checked by the field type B itself. If it is a primitive field, or a reused class, it is not possible, so the A object should check it.
- The **coherence of related fields** (if that B field is null, then C must also be) is the typical responsibility of object A.
- The **coherence of a field B with other codes that are external to A** is another matter. This is where the "pojo" approach (in Java, but applicable to any language) comes into play.

---

The **POJO** approach says that with all the responsibilities/concerns that we have in modern software (persistance & validation are only two of them), domain model end up being messy and hard to understand. The problem is that these domain objects are central to the understanding of the whole application, to communicating with domain experts and so on. Each time you have to read a domain object code, you have to handle the complexity of all these concerns, while you might care of none or one...

So, in the POJO approach, your domain objects must not carry code related to one of these concerns (which usually carries an interface to implement, or a superclass to have).
All concern except the domain one are out of the object (but some simple information can still be provided, in java usually via Annotations, to parameterize generic external code that handle one concern).

Also, the domain objects relate only to other domain objects, not to some framework classes related to one concern (such as validation, or persistence). So the domain model, with all classes, can be put in a separate "package" (project or whatever), without dependencies on technical or concern-related codes. This make it much easier to understand the heart of a complex application, without all that complexity of these secondary aspects.

Answer (score 2):

Validation is a part of the encapsulation- an object is responsible for it's internal state, and validation **is** part of it's internal state.

It's like asking "should I let an object do a function and set his own variables or should I user getters to get them all, do the work in an external function and then you setters to set them back?"

Of course you should use a library to do most of the validation- you don't want to implement the "check unsigned values" function in every model, so you implement it at one place and let each model use it in his own code as fit.

Answer (score 1):

The object should validate the data input.  Otherwise every part of the application which assigns data has to apply the same set of tests, and every part of the application which retrieves the persisted data will need to handle the possibility that some other module hasn't done their checks properly.

Incidentally I don't think this is an object-oriented thang.  It applies to any data persistence construct which takes input.  Basically, you're talking Design By Contract preconditions.